# HttpWebRequest calling a page twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

**Problem**: This console app calls a long running webpage hosted on Azure twice.  I want it to call it only once.

The console app fails with a caught exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.  [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419924/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receive/)

If I call the page from Chrome, it runs once (as expected)

```
public class ExtendedWebClient : WebClient
{
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request != null)
            request.Timeout = Timeout;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        return request;
    }

    public ExtendedWebClient()
    {
        Timeout = 1000000; // in ms.. the standard is 100,000
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var taskUrl = "http://secret.net/SendWeeklyEmails.aspx";
        // create a webclient and issue an HTTP get to our url
        try
        {
            using (ExtendedWebClient httpRequest = new ExtendedWebClient())
            {
                var output = httpRequest.DownloadString(taskUrl);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception was: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419924/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-receive)

Comment: @smarx - how did you find that duplicate? Just interested

Comment: Can you run fiddler and monitor the traffic to see whats going on?

Comment: @Pete2k I read everything with the "azure" tag, so I'd just seen it. :)

Comment: I linked the duplicate in the question.. thought it may help people googling in the future, and tried to attack problem a different way.  Appreciated everyone.  Fiddler didn't work.. Wireshark gave me a clue to a possible keepalive by Chrome after 45secs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - I don't believe this client calls the page twice!

If your call is long running and Azure doesn't allow you to do long-polling, then you will need to rearchitect this app so that you have separate calls for starting and then progress monitoring this "SendWeeklyEmails" task. You could even do this using your command line client code, instead of using the web app.

Comment: Am going to close the question - yes a rearchitect as a console app is the way forward. Thanks.